# Java Insert randomly into String

Tags: java, string, random

How do i insert a random variable into a string?
I created a a variable that gets me a random position in the string that i want to put a char in, but I do not know how to use that random value in order to put that char in that certain position. Here is the code I did to get the random variable-

```
r=0+Math.random()*intTop;
```

I know this gives me a double, which is why i will cast it later. intTop is the length of the string that i will put the char in. I did this substring and it does not work,-

```
stringTop=stringTop.substring((int)r,lastBot);
```

lastBot is the char variable that i want to insert at position r of the string.  Please help I am truly stuck.

Comment: `stringTop.substring(0, r) + lastBot + stringTop.substring(r)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Strings are immutable which means you cannot modify a String in place. Rather, you should create a new string. You can accomplish this by splitting the original string into two parts and inserting the new character in between. Something like this,

```
stringTop.substring(0, r) + lastBot + stringTop.substring(r);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: For the last part, would I add Top.substring(lengthofstring +1) instead of Top.substring(r)? r is the random part of the string that the character gets added to.

Comment: @user2146662 - what aseldawy wrote is correct. stringTop.substring(r) returns the substring starting at position r and going to the end of the string.   Well, correct assuming you want to insert a character (make the string one character longer).  If you wanted to replace the character, you'd say r + 1 instead of r, instead.

Comment: I did this -  stringTop=stringTop + stringTop.substring(0,(int) r) + lastBot + stringTop.substring((int)r+ 1);    and it gives me an error D:

Answer (score 0):

to put a char in a certain position of a string

```
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    chars[r] = c;
    str = new String(chars);
```

or

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    sb.setCharAt(r, c);
    str = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Do i need to import anything for this?

Comment: nothing, all is in java.lang. r - is your random index, str - string, c - character to set